# Are Graduate Schools Less Likely to Fund and/or Accept Nontraditional Students?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, united-states, emotional-responses

I once heard that nontraditional students are less likely to be funded for graduate school. Supposedly (according to this person), this is because 40+ year old students rarely get tenure track positions. Thus, I guess they aren't profitable for the school/program (perhaps unless they're self-funded). I wanted to ask if there was any truth to this.

I'm in my late 30's and am deciding if/where to apply for a master's degree (in a humanities field), but my long term goal is a PhD. Even at the master's level, however, would I have difficulty getting funding at my age?

Also, are nontraditional students more likely to be rejected? I know we present more of a risk for the program, as we're statistically more likely to develop health issues, have fewer productive years in the field, etc. Do admissions committees take this into consideration when evaluating nontraditional applicants?

*Edit- I understand that discrimination is illegal, but this can be difficult to prove since all they have to find is one flaw in your application or decide that you're not a good "fit" for the program. (And my questions is not about winning a discrimination case but about initial acceptance vs. rejection.)

Comment: Arte you using "nontraditional" to mean "OLD"?

Comment: How would admission committees know your age?

Comment: They ask for transcripts from all institutions of higher education, and I have some credits from a community college around 20 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

> this is because 40+ year old students rarely get tenure track positions.

False.  PhD students of any age rarely get tenure track positions.

> Even at the master's level, however, would I have difficulty getting funding at my age?

Not because of your age; however, PhD funding is more common than master's funding.

> Also, are nontraditional students more likely to be rejected?

In most cases, no.  You may experience confusion if the program has never had a nontraditional applicant.

Comment: I think your answer to the first question is taking it overly literal :-) I'm pretty sure it meant to say "This is because 40+ year old students get TT positions even more rarely than those under 40."

Comment: Also, do departments even use TT positions of graduated students as a metric of success? Overall job placement, no matter gov't, academia, industry, etc. is the more common metric in my experience.

Comment: Not any sane departments.

Answer (score 1):

While I don’t think outright discrimination is the norm, I have heard admissions committees say that a long break between degrees shows you are not as committed or dedicated to an academic path as someone who went straight through. This does amount to preference for younger applicants.

You can counteract this in two ways: first, by explaining your career rationale and goals post-degree clearly in your Statement of Interest; and, second, by going directly from your Master’s to PhD as a full-time student for both.

In addition, as Paul notes, you should ask your letter writers to speak to your commitment to grad school in their letters.

Comment: Agreed... but it can go the opposite way, too: instead of the without-thinking go-straight-through of very young people, sometimes I have the impression (on grad admissions ctes) that older people who've tried some other things have a much clearer commitment to grad school, and can be more mature and stable...

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes, as long as they and their letter writers give testimony and evidence to that effect!